# Can't set headers after they are sent. Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Help me :(, i cannot find solution for my error, i try using return before my response it dosen't work

[this my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk1uN.png)

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
var getToken = req.cookies.token;
var getUrl = req.originalUrl;
console.log(getToken)    
if(getToken == undefined) {
    res.redirect('/login')
    next()
} else {
    console.log('success')
    next()
}
next() }

router.get('/login', isAuthenticated, auth.login);
router.get('/logout', isAuthenticated, auth.logout);
router.post('/logging', auth.prosesLogin);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: you have solution for my code?

Comment: Remove `next()` after `else {  }` and in the `if` condition. You must redirect to the endpoint only if authentication has been successful (i.e. calling `next()`). Otherwise, you must redirect to `/login`. (here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h0e2hsau/1/ )

Comment: but wait it's still loop,. GET /auth/logout and, my error it's not show up anymore, but still not redirect to /auth/login url :(

Comment: @Subiyantoro remove `isAuthenticated` from `GET @ /login` endpoint. No point to validate if person is not logged in yet, right?

Comment: @alwaysone yes that's right, but later i want GET @ /login using isAuthenticated middleware to for checking if user request to url @ /login and authenticated it will be redirect to another page. that's code for example i testing my middleware for redirecting page but still error :(

Comment: Let's move to the chat [here](http://www.e-chat.co/room/220911)

Comment: @alwaysone i'm on :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in your functions, the order of function arguments is wrong.

Instead of `(err, res)` make `(req, res)` or `(err, req, res, next)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `next()` with `return false`.